# how to get milliseconds from date in android

Tags: android, kotlin, date

as the title suggests, I want to get millisecond from a specific date, and this is the solution that I am using. Please suggest if there is a better way to do this if you know so.

## What is the need for Millisecond?

For my use case, it was to limit the starting and ending time-period selection in an Android `DatePickerDialog` box. [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog). It can be done using

1. `dpd.datePicker.maxDate` (where `dpd` is the object of the `DatePickerDialog` that I created) [maxDate Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker#getMaxDate())
2. `dpd.datePicker.maxDate` [minDate documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker#getMinDate())

These take in the milliseconds in long format and restrict the max/min dates of the DatePickerDialogue box accordingly.

## How to get milliseconds of specific dates?

(I'll put that as the answer)

First, I created a Calander instance to get the desired dates for the limits.

```
        val c1 = Calendar.getInstance()
        // This will set the max date of the calendar, as the last day of the previous month rather than the current date (default)
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 0)

        val c2 = Calendar.getInstance()
        // This will set the min year as 10 years before from today.
        c2.add(Calendar.YEAR, -10)
```

But now I need to get the milliseconds of those specific dates.

Comment: `getTimeInMillis()`?

Comment: Consider not using `Calendar`. That class is cumbersome to work with and long outdated. Look into using [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html). Your code may be a few lines longer, but much clearer to read and future-proof.

Comment: Start by `ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());`. From this variable you can then get `now.minusMonths(1).with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth()).toInstant().toEpochMilli()` (just gave 1 680 289 322 893) and `now.minusYears(10).toInstant().toEpochMilli()` (1 366 398 122 893). It’s not only a better way, it’s a *way better* way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the milliseconds from calendar instance like this:-

```
    val c1 = Calendar.getInstance()

    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 0)
    val c2 = Calendar.getInstance()
    c2.add(Calendar.YEAR, -10)

    val startTime: Long = c2.getTimeInMillis()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution :**

To convert the calendar instance dates to milliseconds.

```
(c1.time).time
(c2.time).time
```

So now the limit can be placed as

```
dpd.datePicker.maxDate = (c1.time).time
dpd.datePicker.minDate = (c2.time).time
```

**Explanation :**

From a calendar instance `c1/c2`, the first `.time` (which is a '*property access syntax*' of `Calendar.getTime()` [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime--)) will return a `Date` object in the eg format `Tue Mar 14 10:20:30 UTC 2023`.

Now the second `.time` (eventhough looks same) is a *property access syntax* of `Date.getTime()` [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime()). This `.time`, takes a `Date` object (which here was passed by the first `.time`) and returns the 'milliseconds from Epoch' of that particular date.

Thus we can get the milliseconds from epoch of any particular date using `.time` or `.time.time` depending on what you have to pass.